# Batch script - Look for String "Name" return ID corresponding to the string

Tags: file, batch-file, command-line, cmd, web-deployment

I have a script that look for a String "SiteName" in a file. What i want to do is If string = "SiteName" return corresponding ID number.

```
@echo off
set SiteID
%SiteID% = findstr /s /b "SiteName" %WinDir%\System32\Inetsrv\Config\applicationHost.Config
```

In my File i Have this `<site name="SiteName" id="3" serverAutoStart="true">` I want to store the ID in %SiteID% variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1-3delims=<=> " %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 if "%%a"=="site" if "%%b"=="name" set siteid=%%~c
)
echo %siteid%
```

Will search the filename for a line which is structured as

*delimiters***site***delimiters***name***delimiters***"requireddata"***whatever*

where *delimiters* are any of `<`,`=`,`>` or <kbd>Space</kbd>

The `usebackq` allows the filename (which may be a constant as you nominate) to be quoted (required if it contains separators), and the `~` removes any quotes around the third token (a token is the string between the delimiter-strings)

Comment: I tested and it works for me if I get token from `1` to `5` and in the `set` command I use the `%%~e` variable.

Comment: in this case %filename% is the path to the file?

Comment: Yes - I used a variable to contain the filename.

Comment: Wow! That works Thank you!! I replaced %filename1% with the path to the file Great!

Comment: One more question, Does this search for the SiteName site? and the corresponding ID number because i have multiple website with diffrent ID numbers.

Comment: No - as I read your question, you only wanted the `sitename`. To add the `id`, simply extend the `tokens` to `1-5` and set the id using `set sitename=%%~c&set siteid=%%~e` which will give you both the site name and ID from the line in question. Now - if you have more than one such line in your file, then you need to make modifications, since a batch variable may normally only contain one value at a time.

Comment: I have found a solution thanks to @Magoo Great answer thanks!